# Connect domain with localhost on vps

Tags: dns, xampp, hosting, vps, host

Okay, so i have windows vps that works good. I have installed xampp and configured everything so now when i use my vps ip address other people can also access my website when using ip as a domain name. now, i have a domain name that i want to use, so i was wondering if somebody can explain me how to connect my domain name with windows vps xampp?
Also, i don't know much so i need someone to explain it step by step if possible.

The website works good and vps is hosting it, other people can access it and they have no problems and the only thing I want is to connect my domain to vps. hopefully this is possible.

thanks in advance. cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your DNS settings with your domain registrar to point to your web servers IP address.